# How to communicate between background services

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, intentservice

I am implementing an app, in that I have two Services. One does some task and pass some value to another service and that service does some task using this value. When the first Service generate first value it should start 2nd service. Here after the values generated by the first service will be added in a queue in 2nd service. First time when the 2nd service starts I can set the value in queue using intent, but I don't know how to communicate after starting the 2nd service. How to communicate between these to services.

Anybody have some idea on this please do help me.

Comment: instead of two service use one service... create methods in service do all your task in one... its good.. also consume less Power.

Comment: both are heavy tasks, that's why I am using 2 services..

Comment: "both are heavy tasks, that's why I am using 2 services" -- that makes little sense. What makes you think that using two services is somehow better than using one service?

Comment: @CommonsWare actually two tasks are happening in background like converting file and uploading file. I am maintaining a Queue in 2nd Service to upload file. Converting file will happen fast and it will put converted file details to Upload queue. Uploading file will take time. I thought it is better to use different services for these two tasks. If I am wrong please let me know.

Comment: "I thought it is better to use different services for these two tasks" -- not especially. In fact, unless the user, on the device, will use the converted file, there is only one task: convert-and-upload. There is no particular advantage for using multiple services here, and doing so causes the very communication problems that you are trying to address.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the advice, I am trying to do it in single Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my understanding, you may communicate in two ways:

1. [`Bind`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) your service(s)
2. make use of [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) within your service(s) to exchange data/commands

However, I would suggest you not to complicate your design by involving multiple services. In fact, you should decide either you really need an ordinary service or can it be done via [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).